# HTML5 (php) with CSS Tooltip shows up far away from hyperlink

Tags: php, html, css, tooltip

If I hover over the hyperlink, the tooltip shows up but not as it should. It shows up a few inches below the hyperlink. I got the code from a demo of the internet.

How do I get the tooltip right below the hyperlink?

Here is the **PHP** code I used:

```
if ($teller == 3) {
    echo '<p><a href="#" class="tooltip">...<span>';

    foreach ($bericht->datums as $date) {
        echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($date->datum)) . ' om ' . date('H:i', strtotime($date->beginUur)) . '<br />';
    }

        echo '</span></a></p>';
    }
```

The code above generated this code in **HTML**:

```
<p>
   <a href="#" class="tooltip">...
      <span>
         13/04/2013 om 13:49<br />
         15/04/2013 om 12:50<br />
         29/04/2013 om 16:00<br />
      </span>
   </a>
 </p>
```

Here is the **CSS** that belongs to it:

```
a.tooltip span {
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    white-space:nowrap;
    bottom:9999px;    
    background:#81b0b0;
    color:#e0e0e0;
    padding:5px 12px;
    line-height: 24px;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 0;
    transition:opacity 0.5s ease-out;
    }

a.tooltip span::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    border-left: 6px solid #81b0b0;
    border-top: 6px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: -6px;
    left: 0px;
}

a.tooltip:link {
    color:#FFF;
}

a.tooltip:visited {
    color:#FFF;
}

a.tooltip:hover span {
    opacity: 1;
    bottom:-35px;
    }
```

Can someone help me out please? Thanks! ;)

Comment: +1 for posting the generated code, that really helped me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use

```
position:absolute;
```

it positions against the nearest container in the chain that has a position set; so if you don't have a position set on any of the elements that contain it, or its parents, it will position against the body.

try putting position absolute or relative on the containing p tag

Comment: I made it relative and display: block and it's better now. But now it keeps getting underlined, even with text-decoration: none.